# Delete all rows from one of the duplicate datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, datatable

I have two datatables dt1 and dt2 i copied dt2 into dt1 and clear all rows from dt2.But fact is that data get cleared from both datatables rather than only one. following is the code.

```
 dt1= dt2
 dt2.Rows.Clear()
```

here all rows from dt1 also get deleted? is there any better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the datatable to your new datatable e.g.

```
dt1= dt2.Copy();
dt2.Rows.Clear();
```

Currently when you are assigning dt2 to dt1, reference of dt2 is assigned.